# Read a cell value from another excel file

Tags: excel

If I want to read a value from another sheet, I write in the cell

```
='sheetName2'!G40
```

If I want to read the above value in a different excel file, can this happen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just refer to the file, like:

```
='C:\Users\James\Desktop\[Other.xlsx]Sheet1'!$B$9
```

Comment: do you know if this apply also if the files are stored in google drive?

Comment: Ok I found it. I need `importrange` function for google drive

Answer (score 1):

The formula should look something like: 
  ='[File Name.xlsx]Sheet1'!D2

Or you can find it by going through Excel's workbooks feature which allows you to open up another Excel file, just like everything I know the sheet with missing file. This is for Excel 2010, be careful moving files around that may cause the links to break.